# xdt:Transform fails to change mailsettings

Tags: xsd, web-config

Before I start I would like to say that I have read and tried all methods/solutions I can find on this and other forums to no avail.

I have a simple mail setting entry in my webconfig that I want transformed when publishing to test environment etc.

This is the main config that uses my local settings

```
<system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp from="p.carey@sentinelwater.co.uk">
            <network host="SENTINEL-SBS" port="25" />
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
      </system.net>
```

and this is one of the attempted transforms

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreply@test.managemywater.co.uk" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <network xdt:Transform="Replace" host="localhost" port="25" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

It simply fails on replacing 'host' with localhost and maintains SENTINEL-SBS. I have no idea if it attempts to replace 'from'.

I have run out of ideas and will have to resort to translating Japanese forums now!!!

No doubt there is a simple answer but I'll be damned if I can find it.

I have an addition transform for the connection string using 'add name' and that works fine.

Comment: What does it have to do with `xsd` if it's `transform`? Shouldn't it be `xsl`? Why have you wrote `xdt:Transform` with `xdt` and capitalized `T`?

Comment: Typo, my apologies. The capitalized T is how it comes from intellisense.

Any input on the question?

Comment: Just've read about xdt the first time, but I think I could help. Is there `xmlns:xdt` attribute anywhere in the xml?

Comment: According to manual `xdt:Transform="Replace"` must have an `xdt:Locator` nearby.

Comment: there is 

         <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-     Document-Transform"> 

There is a locator on the connection transform that uses a name attribute but I can't see how it would be used as whenever i attempt to add the name attribute it wont accept in any format i try.

Comment: `Locator` should be on `network` element in your example. Yet I can't get its exact meaning from the manual.

Comment: I have tried this to no avail

     `
    <system.net>
      <mailSettings>
         <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" xdt:Transform="Replace">
          <network host="localhost" port="25" />
        </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
      </system.net>
    `

I had to leave the from attribute out as well as it wouldn't accept it

Comment: `smtp` element doesn't have `xdt:Locator` on it either.